# Laravel .env in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-7

I have deployed my Laravel application to **AWS Beanstalk**. I also connected **CodePipeline** for automatic deployment. As I have multiple environments (staging, testing, production) I want to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment variables for different environments. However, when I write my own variables to elastic  beanstalk configuration and I `dd(config('app.env'))`, it prints ***"production"*** instead of  ***"staging"***. How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

P.s: I also removed the .env file manually, it still did not work.

[image: env]

Comment: I think you have your settings cached. If you run `php artisan config:clear` this should clear the cached config. You can also run `php artisan config:cache` to refresh the existing cache

Comment: @RobBiermann unfortunately it did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon first check it's global variables (google it pls) and then refers to laravel .env file variables